# Does intellij run maven as a different user?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I have configured the enforcer to check for some properties. These are exported as environment variables in my `.profile` file in my home dir. The build from the console runs fine.

The build from intellij (doubleclicking the goals in the maven menu) fails, as enforcer cannot find the properties...What is going wrong here and how to fix it?

My first guess is that intellij is running maven as a different user but I'm not sure how to verify it or what to do about it.

NOTE: I am not asking for a workaround. One would be to set the properties in maven Runner settings of intellij, a second - to set the properties in `/etc/profile`. But I would like to avoid them.

**EDIT** :  I have tried restarting intellij, the X server and the machine - to no effect on the enforcer. `printenv` in a fresh console shows my variables as expected. Starting intellij from the same console leads to the same build failure.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to configure maven or any other plugin or program to run as a different user in IntelliJ.

Comment: I assumed it by analogy to the jenkins server, which runs maven as the jenkins user - I could find no other explanation

Answer (score 2):

Each program has its own environment.  If you change the environment settings in `.profile` or the like, it doesn't change the setting for running programs.  When one program runs another program it inherits the settings/environment of its parent. It doesn't load the settings again.

What you could be finding is that changes you make after IntelliJ has started, have no effect from programs IntelliJ runs.  The same thing would happen if you opened a command window, changed the settings and run a new programs (the shell would keep the settings it had when it started) To fix this you need to re-start IntelliJ.  If you run it from the command line, make sure its a new window.

---

This unit test should dump the environment.

```
@Test
public void dumpEnv() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : new TreeMap<String, String>(System.getenv()).entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I have tried the low hanging fruits already - restarting intellij, the x server or the machine has no effect. I am not exporting the variables manually, but through my `.profile`, so the environment should be same for all applications. Have edited the question to relect this.

Comment: In that case I would check the same version of maven run from the command line does the same thing.

Comment: have tried that - "The build from the console runs fine." Intellij uses the same binary/M2_HOME as the console build. Jenkins uses it too, but for CI I use the injectEnv plugin to avoid changing the global profile

Comment: Can you try setting it explicitly on the command line (full path name) and in intelliJ to check that.

Comment: Can you create a simple unit test which dumps all the environment variables? This will tell you if they are the same.

Comment: tried full path and doublechecked IDE maven settings...same success from console/failure from intellij :( Will try the test

Comment: tested, running test from intellij - env vars are as they should be, using System.getenv(). Thanks for bearing with me :)

Comment: in spite of seemingly having the same environment, maven build still fails from intellij

Comment: Try printing the `System.getProperties()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

`.profile` is only executed when you log on using KSH. If you use BASH, it has no effect.

[`.bashrc` (if you use BASH)](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html) is a much more suitable place because it's executed every time you start a shell (shell scripts, new terminal windows, etc).

For KSH, [`.kshrc` has the same effect](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/SHL_custom/_The_Korn_shell_profile_and_kshrc.html).

To make sure the variables are there, use `set` (no options) to list all of them or `set|grep`*pattern* to search. As soon as they show up in a new terminal window, they should be there from inside your IDE, too.

**[EDIT]** If `set` can see them, so can IntelliJ. The only thing left is that IntelliJ could clean the environment when it starts Maven.

To test that, rename `mvn` to `mvn.orig` and create a new script `mvn` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
set > $HOME/mvn_env.log
mvn.orig "$@"
```

This script dumps the environment as `mvn` sees it to `$HOME/mvn_env.log`. If the variables are missing, then IntelliJ cleans the environment.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I am using bash (says `echo $0`) and set the variables nowhere else but in the .profile. They are set when I restart and are available - checked with `set`, `printenv`, `System.getenv()'. I migrated them to .bashrc - seems to have changed nothing

Comment: If `set` can see them, so can IntelliJ. The only thing left is that IntelliJ could clean the environment when it starts Maven. See my edits.